# save() callback not being invoked on a mongoose schema object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Im trying to save a json object in my database. The save() function is not being called but and the json object is never saved.
Help me figure out the problem.
I guess it's a connection problem with mongoose.
Here is my code..

```
    var config = require('../config');
    var user = require('../user');
api.post('/addUser',function(req,res) {
    var userID;
    //creating a sample user under Model collection User.. so this becomes a document!!
    console.log("addition of new user api hit!!");
    //sending a query to retrieve the no of users served
    MongoClient.connect(dbURL, function (err, db) {
        var UserCountCursor = db.collection("ourusers").find({"docName": "userCount"}).limit(1);

        UserCountCursor.each(function (err, doc) {
            if (err)
                console.log("did not get the count");
            else
            // var countString= JSON.stringify(doc);
            //var docJson=JSON.parse(countString);
                console.log("the json content is:" + doc.iparkoUserCount);

            //increase the user count by 1 in the db.
            var incCount = parseInt(doc.iparkoUserCount) + 1;
            console.log("no of userrs:" + incCount);
            // making an userId
            userID = "ipkoID_C" + incCount.toString();
            //updating using MOngoClient
            db.collection("ourusers").update({"docName": "userCount"}, {$set: {"iparkoUserCount": incCount}});
            console.log("the user count in the db has been updated!!");
            console.log("generated id for this guy is:" + userID);

            if (userID != null) {
                console.log("calling the save function");
                //closing the mongoclient connection
                db.close();
                signUpUser(userID);
            }
        });
    });


    function signUpUser(userIDD) {
        var me = new user({
            name: req.body.new_name,
            password: req.body.new_pswd,
            username: req.body.new_username,
            phno: req.body.new_phn,
            userId: userIDD
        });

        console.log("the obj ::" + JSON.stringify(me));
        console.log("obj created and ready to be stored");
//connecting to the db using mongoose
        mongoose.connect(config.database, function (err) {
            if (err)
                console.log("The error is :"+err);
            else {
                console.log("WE ARE CONNECTED USING MONGOOSE");
                //saving the sample user document
                me.save(function (err) {
                    console.log("in the save func");
                    if (err) throw err;
                    else {
                        console.log('User saved Successfully!!!!!');
                        res.json({
                            'whatStatus': 'user saved in the database!!',
                            'userID': userIDD
                        });
                        mongoose.connection.close();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

My console logs::

> addition of new user api hit!!
>   the json content is:143
>   no of userrs:144
>   the user count in the db has been updated!!
>   generated id for this guy is:ipkoID_C144
>   calling the save function
>   the obj ::{"name":"Abhi","password":"jio","username":"abhijio","phno":"45142545","userId":"ipkoID_C144","_id":"583295bfa0f9f8342035d3b9"}
>   obj created and ready to be stored
>   C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:98
>       process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
>                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'iparkoUserCount' of null
    at C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\routes\RegisteredParkingLots.js:76:57
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
    at C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:742:16
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
    at C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:676:5
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:156:5)
    at setCursorDeadAndNotified (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:496:3)
    at nextFunction (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:588:12)
    at Cursor.next [as _next] (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:681:3)
    at nextObject (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:673:8)
    at Cursor.next (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:262:12)
    at _each (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:738:10)
    at C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:746:7
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:96:12)
    at C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cursor.js:676:5
    at handleCallback (C:\Users\shivendra\WebstormProjects\iParko\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\cursor.js:156:5)

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be opening the db connection twice one with `mongoose.connect` and another one with  `mongoose.connection.open()`. That's why you are getting error.

Try using this with just one connection as below.

```
mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err, db) {
            //var dbcon=mongoose.connection.open();

            //dbcon.on('error',function(){console.log('connction error:')});
            //dbcon.once('open',function(){
   if(err) {
      console.log(err);
   } else {
                console.log("WE ARE CONNECTED USING MONGOOSE");
                //saving the sample user document
                me.save(function (err) {
                    console.log("in the save func");
                    if (err) throw err;
                    else {
                        console.log('User saved Successfully!!!!!');
                        res.json({
                            'whatStatus': 'user saved in the database!!',
                            'userID': userIDD
                        });
                        //mongoose.connection.close();
                    }
                });
          }
    });
```

Comment: Aruna I tried this out but still im not getting into the save() function. I've updated my code in the question as well as the console logs.. Might want to have a look.. - Thanks for the help

Comment: The error is `Cannot read property 'iparkoUserCount' of null`. Can you check this error?

Comment: Actually that iparkoUserCount variable is a doc key. Now inside doc.each(...) function im logging the variable content okay. But that doc has only one json object. So for the very first time when each() runs it doesn't give that error but when that only object that was in the doc is read and the doc is now empty( since it had a single json obj only). Now when the each() function runs it doesn't find any other json object to read and hence throws that error . Thats why I've used signUpUser(userIDD) function which gets called once the user id is made. And the control is entering the signUpUser()

Comment: May I know where you are creating the `user` schema, since `mongoose.connect` should be called once before the `schema` creation. Once you did this, `mongoose.connect` is not required at the time of `me.save`.

Comment: Ohh.. Im creating my Schema in another JS file named user.js and then i'm importing that file to this current JS file :: var user= require('../user');

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `UserCountCursor.each(...)` loop, after checking for `err` you should also check for `doc`. So where you have this:

```js
UserCountCursor.each(function (err, doc) {
   if (err)
     console.log("did not get the count");
   else 

     // var countString= JSON.stringify(doc);

     //...

})
```

do this instead:

```js
UserCountCursor.each(function (err, doc) {
   if (err){
     console.log("did not get the count");
   }else if(doc){ 

     // var countString= JSON.stringify(doc);

     //...

   }

})
```

Then you will avoid the `Cannot read property 'iparkoUserCount' of null` error and you'll get into your `save()` function.

Comment: Thanx Stephen !! That really worked.. that was easy.. Thanx for all the help.